# Is there a way to prevent sed from adding carriage return (^M)?

Tags: php, wordpress, bash, sed

I am trying to add `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');` after the `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` in a wordpress php file.

Here is what I tried so far:

1-

```
sed -b -i "/'WP_DEBUG', false);/a define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');" $full_path/wp-config.php;
```

2-

```
 sed -i "s/'WP_DEBUG', false);/'WP_DEBUG', false);\ndefine('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');/" $full_path/wp-config.php;
```

The problem with that, all the new lines being replaced with this carriage return char. How can I add a new line after a specific line and do not have this issue ?

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);^M
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');
```

Using sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2, Ubuntu 16.04

Here is the screenshots for clarify the issue:

[image]

[image]

Comment: GNU sed, on Ubuntu, adding Windows line endings? That seems unlikely.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bh0y24

Comment: So every line has one? So they were there before you were running sed? Get rid of them, then run sed, I'll bet they don't get added. Not that I can answer why it would be left in place...

Comment: no. you've got it wrong. http://prntscr.com/bh1020

Comment: Are you sure that all those carriage returns aren't there before you run your command? It looks as though the line you've appended is the only one that doesn't have one.

Comment: I am sure. Check the screenshot http://prntscr.com/bh119k

Comment: You're showing screenshots from different programs/terminals, some of which may be configured to quietly handle windows-style line endings. Use something like `od -c file.php` to check the file before and after the substitution.

Comment: What is the file line ending ? Is it CRLF (Windows) ? I already had this issue on windows created files when editing them on linux, it added ^M on each updated lines. If this is the case, you need to change the file line ending

Comment: Something else is going on here. I'm 99% certain, this is nothing to do with sed.

Comment: The file is original file from wordpress https://wordpress.org/latest.zip and name of it is wp-config-sample.php

http://prntscr.com/bh140p

Comment: Rather than posting all of these screenshots in the comments, just run `od -c wp-config.php` before and after the substitution and [edit] your question to show the output for the relevant lines.

Comment: Ok it must be this : wp-config-sample has CRLF line ending

Comment: You don't need `s` command for `sed`. You can use `"/'WP_DEBUG', false);/a define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');\r"`

Comment: Why do you need sed for this? Why not use any text editor?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The file originally has CRLF line endings. When you open it in `vim` editor, vim understands that file has CRLF endings & **hides** them from user. Any new line/s added via the editor will also have the same line endings as the rest of the file.

When you add a new line via `sed`, it has `LF` line endings. Next time when you open it in `vim`, vim sees mixed line endings, `CRLF` & `LF`. `vim` then decides to interpret it as file with `LF` line endings. & all `CR` characters are highlighted as `^M`.

to test, try this:

```
$ printf '%d\r\n' {1..5} > test_endings # This will create a file with CRLF endings.
$ file test_endings 
test_endings: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ vim test_endings
1
2
3
4
5
~
~
"test_endings" [dos] 5L, 15C        <~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Notice the word DOS here.

$ echo 6 >> test_endings # This will add line with LF line endings.
$ file test_endings 
test_endings: ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
$ vim test_endings
1^M
2^M
3^M
4^M
5^M
6
~
~
"test_endings" 6L, 17C
```

In short, the issue is not with `sed`, it's with the original file.

Comment: Great explanation, It helped me to solve the issue thank you. Please check the note that I added :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert line ending from DOS format to unix format :

```
sed 's/^M$//' $full_path/wp-config.php > $full_path/wp-config.php
```

More methods here : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/

Comment: `^M` is actually a single character, @micster. It is the line-feed character (`\r` in `C` language and friends).

Comment: `some_command filename > filename` is almost never what you want. The redirection operator `>` will truncate the file before the `some_command` start processing it. Either use `some_command filename > filename.new && mv filename.new filename` or use an option like `--in-place` if your command supports it. (`sed` does.)

Answer (score 0):

After using sed, run dos2unix to convert to unix format and it will remove the "^M".

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
sed -i "s/'WP_DEBUG', false);/'WP_DEBUG', false);\ndefine('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');/" $full_path/wp-config.php;
dos2unix $full_path/wp-config.php
```

Answer (score -1):

Tested, can't replicate.

The file does contain windows line endings to begin with in Wordpress itself. (see [the sample file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/WordPress/master/wp-config-sample.php)).

Running the command posted (number 2), results in

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);                                                      
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');^M
```

which is expected behaviour, which, while not the output in OP's original question, is exactly what they show they get in their screenshots.

Comment: I think @micster has a point. The file from https://wordpress.org/latest.zip here has windows CRLF file endings.

Comment: and if you try number 1 it will be like in the questions output.