# Echo outputting content of variable & enclosed in double quotes appends ^M (bash)

Tags: bash, echo, newline

I got a line of code in bash that is supposed to output this:

`identity="A273927A49D0"` (The content of `identity` is stored in `$usercaps`)

My line of code is:
`echo "identity=\"$usercaps\"" >> ttls.conf`

However if I do that, the output becomes: `identity="A273927A49D0^M"`

I can get around it by adding this:
`echo "identity=\"$usercaps\"" | sed 's/\r//' >> ttls.conf`

Why is this happening and is this the only way to deal with it?

Comment: What o/s are you running on?

Comment: Then `usercaps` contains `^M` -- how are you obtaining this value?

Comment: `$usercaps` contains the string A273927A49D0. `echo "$usercaps"` gives me `A273927A49D0` The problem arises when I `echo` my string that contains the variable `$usercaps` and the string must also contain quotes.

Comment: When you `echo $usercaps >> ttls.conf` and `less ttls.conf` do you get the ^M after the variable? How are you setting `$usercaps`?

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854454/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-sed-from-adding-carriage-return-m